# how to do partition in ubuntu after installation?

Tags: partitioning

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x344916fc

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048  1945391103   972694528   83  Linux
/dev/sda2      1945393150  1953523711     4065281    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5      1945393152  1953523711     4065280   82  Linux swap / Solaris
shivam@shivam-Inspiron-5521:~$
```

Comment: From your question it is not clear where do you want to do partition? Add some more information and make your question clear. Although I suggestion you to install `gparted`, which is a good tool to add/delete/create/shrink/extend partitions. Search in `Ubuntu software Center` or install it by command: `sudo apt-get install gparted`

Comment: You cannot run gparted from your working install. Generally you have to use your Ubuntu live installer or separate gparted or partedmagic liveCds and even then you have to click on swap and swapoff to unmount swap if working on extended partition.

Comment: Your question seems to be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/164010/236

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer I wrote for someone else but it will help you for certain so I am copying it here.

Hello
It would be easiest to just start from the beginning so lets do that, okay?

First, boot to your USB  or DVD and let Ubuntu start a live session. You will see an icon on the desktop that says Install Ubuntu on your desktop. Launch (click on) it.

When you get to the screen where it asks you if you want to replace an existing install or install next to it or Something Else, choose Something Else.

Now you will see a screen that will let you see the hard drive you want to install to. Make sure you choose the correct drive you want to install ubuntu on! On that screen you will need to first delete any existing partitions so you can start fresh.

Start at the bottom of the listed partitions and right click on each one and choose Delete. After you have done this to all the partitions, click on Apply.

When you have deleted everything your drive will show as completely unallocated space! Sometimes some partitions cannot be deleted right away so delete all you can at first and click Apply, then start over from the bottom until they are all deleted.

Now you want to create the necessary partitions for you to install Ubuntu.

Create the following partitions:

1. a boot partition `/boot` and give it 250 MB of space, choose `ext4` for the format.
2. a root partition `/root` and give it 15000 MB of space and `ext4` format
3. a swap partition `/swap` and give it 4096 MB of space (it will format to swap)
4. a home partition `/home` and give it the rest of the space and format it to `ext4`.

   Now just finish the install and it will run beautifully.