# Install 12.04.3 LTS 64 bit

Tags: system-installation

Installing to newly formatted disk.

Used `Nero` to put image on DVD no errors, but docs say there should be a program folder
    which is not on DVD

Start PC boots DVD get the choice window to `try or install or check` etc.
   but choosing any of those options just results in a system **reset and reboot**.

Is there supposed to be a programs folder? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this tutorial: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if Nero didn't make the copy correctly. Download a free program 

called IMGBURN and use it to burn Ubuntu to a DVD. IMGBURN is very easy 
to use and makes perfect burns. I have found Nero to be quirky over the years. 
You might also want to read an answer I posted about how to do a trouble free
installation of Ubuntu. Here is a link to it:
  [how to do partition in ubuntu after installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355389/how-to-do-partition-in-ubuntu-after-installation/355396#355396)