# İnstalling ubuntu to C:

Tags: installation

I have created a Bootable Usb stick, I will create Ubuntu to C: but I have some saved documents like picture at d: If I install Ubuntu to c: , backup files from d: will erase ?

Comment: Actually  I have no problem because I have not installed ubuntu yet.
 My disk separeted as  c: and d: and I use "d:" backup my pictures, photos something like that. now, If I install ubuntu to c:, My photos will be erased from d: ?

Comment: which back up files do you think will get erased?

Comment: A note for you: Windows is the only OS using multiple root directories (`C:`, `D:`,...). All UNIX-based systems (Linux, Mac OS) only have one root directory: `/`. Other partitions are mounted in subdirectories of this root directory.

Comment: You may want to read the differences between Windows and Linux partitions http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93960/41104

Comment: You have two choices here with differing results.  1) You can use wubi to install the Ubuntu OS as an image stored on drive C: -or- 2) You can have Linux automagically resize your disk partitions so you will have C: and D: plus a Linux partition (well, two, with the swap partition). But, before you do that, how much space do you have free on your hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your disk is partitioned in both `C:` and `D:` directories, then installing Ubuntu on `C:` will not erase the document in `D:`

But the Operating system installed in `C:` will be erased.

However you should NEVER install an OS without a backup of all your documents, because you never know you might make a mistake.

[Here's a great guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu does not use letters (c: or d:) to identify hard drives or partitions.

The first drive is /dev/sda
The second drive is /dev/sdb

Partitions are then numbered, so first partition on the first hard drive is /dev/sda1

As long as you understand partitioning and the target of your installation, your data on the d: drive / partition should be find, BUT ...

Overwriting your data is a mouse click away on the installer and if you do not understand Linux partitioning you can easily loose data.

I suggest you first back up your data off the hard drive, then read the partitioning and installation documentation.

[How to partition my hard drive for Ubuntu use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164010/how-to-partition-my-hard-drive-for-ubuntu-use)

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/

Comment: It should be added that the partitions aren't *mounted* under `/dev/sda1`,... Usually they get mounted in `/media/username/devicename`

Answer (score 0):

since your talking about C: & D: drives--thats for M.S. O.S.,,,use wubi installer then install ubuntu alongside with windows,,that would install your ubuntu to window's c: drive without loosing evrything except for the space used for your ubuntu,,ubuntu and all files under it will be deleted if you reinstall your windows so its better to install ubuntu on a separate partion..

hope that helps.......

Answer (score 0):

you won't lose anything if u use wubi installer for windows cause it will be installed under your C: drive as a windows application and you can select which O.S. to boot from evrytym u start your machine